# What .NET class and method can be used to replace single and double quotes and other special characters in XML?

Tags: xml, replace

I have to replace, for example, single quote with `&apos;` and double quotes with `&quot;` in the values of an XML string so it can be inserted as xml datatype to SQL Server.  However, with String.Replace or Regex.Replace, I am not able to replace characters in the values without replacing characters in the tags.  (E.g., I can't have xsi:nil=`&quot;`true`&quot;`in a tag).
I also tried SecurityElement.Escape(String) Method, but it replaced all tag brackets with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.
Is there an XML class and method in .NET that can be used to target only the XML values and ignore the tags?

Comment: Ideally, you'd use the `Escape()` method _before_ forming the XML...

Comment: I am using XmlReader to get the xml into an SSIS string variable. 

using (XmlReader readFile = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath))
{
readFile.ReadToFollowing("Request");
xmlContent = readFile.ReadOuterXml();
}

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a string like this:

```
<a x="y="3" z="5""/>
```

then sorting out which quotes are intended to be attribute delimiters and which are part of the attribute content is pretty-well impossible (that's why XML insists they must be escaped).

The way you've phrased the question doesn't make sense. "Is there an XML class and method in .NET that can be used to target only the XML values and ignore the tags?" You can only separate the values from the tags by parsing the content as XML, and you can't parse it as XML unless it's already well-formed XML.

If you can find an algorithm to sort out the ambiguity, good for you. But the real answer is, don't start from here. Find a way to avoid being in the hole that you're trying to climb out of.

Comment: I am using XmlReader to get the xml into an SSIS string variable. 
```
using (XmlReader readFile = XmlReader.Create(xmlPath))
{
readFile.ReadToFollowing("Request");
xmlContent = readFile.ReadOuterXml();
}
```
The entire xml is going into a sql table as datatype [xml].  I would think there is a class and method to do replacement in just the values, not the tags.

Comment: Surely the value returned by ReadOuterXml() is well-formed XML and does not need any further escaping? What is the actual string it is returning?

Comment: Maybe it's a file that's claiming to be XML, but isn't...